# how can i use the Entry function in tkinter in an if argument?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i am making a password organisator in python, and i don't know how i can get user input from an Entry and use it in an if argument?

```
text1 = StringVar()
def but():
    text1.get()
    print(text1.get())
    knapp2 = Button(root, command="but").pack()
entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=text1).place(x=270, y=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the .get() function on on the Entry widget too to get the text.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry


mw = Tk()

entry = Entry(mw)
entry.pack()


def but():
    text = entry.get()
    print(text)
    button.config(text='Button Clicked')

button = Button(mw, command=but, text='Test')
button.pack()


mw.mainloop()
```

This code does work but will become complicated with larger code. You will have to define the function before creating a widget that calls that function. In the above example if you created the button widget before the function you would get an exception. You could create the widget, then create the function, then change the configuration of the button to call that function when clicked but that's still pretty complicated and will be confusing in large programs.

I would recommend putting everything in a class. It makes it easy to reference widgets in functions.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry


class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.entry = Entry(self.master)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.master, text='Test', command=self.But)
        self.button.pack()


    def But(self):
        print(self.entry.get())
        self.button.config(text='Button Clicked.')


mw = Tk()

main = Main(mw)

mw.mainloop()
```